# Compare and replace frames/tables specific rows

Tags: r

i just stared with R and i try to compare 2 columns of two different tables.
If the match is true, then i want to replace the specific value (in df1).
I also have the problem, that im very limited about using additional packages since i want to use the script in a database.

df1:

```
DE
Deutschland
England
Germany
Italien
```

df2

```
GE              EN
Deutschland     Germany
Italien         Italy
England         UK
```

Result:
df1:

```
DE
Deutschland
England
**Deutschland**
Italien
```

I tried following code:

```
df1 <- data.frame("DE" = c("Deutschland", "England", "Germany", "Italien"))
df2 <- data.frame("GE" = c("Deutschland", "Italien", "England"), "EN" = c("Germany", "Italy", "UK"))
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.character)
df2[] <- lapply(df2, as.character)

df1 <- ifelse(!(df1$DE %in% df2$EN), df1$DE, df2$GE)
```

Instead of "Deutschland" it replace "England". How can I replace the right row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution using `match` with its `nomatch`-operator:

```
df1$DE[df1$DE %in% df2$EN] <- df2$GE[match(df1$DE, df2$EN, nomatch = 0)]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > df1
>            DE
> 1 Deutschland
> 2     England
> 3 Deutschland
> 4     Italien
> ```

What this does:

- `df1$DE[df1$DE %in% df2$EN]` indicates which rows in `df1` need a replacement.
- `df2$GE[match(df1$DE, df2$EN, nomatch = 0)]` selects the replacements from `df2`.
- The latter can be assigned to the former with `<-`.

As pointed out by @r2evans in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045016/compare-and-replace-frames-tables-specific-rows#comment83061603_48045118), `%in%` uses `match` under the hood. Based on that knowledge you could also do:

```
ind <- match(df1$DE, df2$EN, nomatch = 0)
df1$DE[ind > 0] <- df2$GE[ind]
```

Because the index `ind` is now only created once, this may lead to a considerable spead increase on large datasets.

---

You could also do this with an update join with `data.table`:

```
# load the package
library(data.table)

# convert the dataframes to data.table's
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

# perform the update join
df1[df2, on = .(DE = EN), DE := GE][]
```

which gives the same result:

> ```
>             DE
> 1: Deutschland
> 2:     England
> 3: Deutschland
> 4:     Italien
> ```

Comment: `%in%` uses `match`. With large datasets, it might be advantageous to use `ind <- match(df1$DE, df2$EN, nomatch = 0)` followed by `df1$DE[ind > 0] <- df2$GE[ind]`. (With this small dataset, it's already around 30% faster, though that time difference is not significant.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation :)